# How can I add a search feature to my Drupal 7 Zen child theme frontpage?

Tags: search, theming

I would like to add a search form to the front page. I've added this to my template.php:

```
function my_theme_preprocess_page(&$variables){
   $search_box = drupal_render(drupal_get_form('search_form'));
   $variables['search_box'] = $search_box;
}
```

I've added this to my page.tpl.php:

```
<?php print $search_box; ?>
```

After viewing my site I do see the search form but get this error:

> Strict warning: Only variables should be passed by reference in
>   denta_quest_preprocess_page() (line 142 of
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\themes\my_theme\template.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your probably getting the warning because the function takes its argument by reference and to pass a variable by reference it needs to be defined. You're passing a function call which isn't a variable.

Try the following...

```
$search_form = drupal_get_form('search_form');
$search_box = drupal_render($search_form);
$variables['search_box'] = $search_box;
```

Comment: It didn't work, I was able to see the search form but I'm still getting a warning.